# javascript anonymous function syntax

Tags: javascript, anonymous-function

What is the difference between the following two blocks?

```
// block 1
{
    console.log("anonymous block");
}

// block 2
(function anon() {
    console.log("anonymous block 2");
})();
```

I ran this in Netbeans (using the node.js plugin) and they both seem to work...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The difference is that you can use the latter form to hide global variables without destroying them.

For example, suppose you're using the jQuery library, which by default aliases its main namespace to `$`. If you wanted to use `$` for a different purpose without changing how `$` is normally used, you could do something like this:

```
(function($) {
    // Use $ without clashing with the jQuery object.
})(someObject);
```

In fact, it's also useful for one other purpose. Since `undefined` is NOT a reserved word in JavaScript, it can be given a value and lose its purpose. So you could simply not pass a value into an `undefined` parameter, and you know it will behave properly without clashing with a global value.

```
undefined = "some not-undefined value";    // you'd have to be an idiot to do this but I've seen it done
(function(a, b, undefined) {
    console.log(typeof(undefined) === "undefined");   // true
})(someA, someB);
```

Comment: In addition, it can also be used in the module pattern. (See http://stackoverflow.com/a/12325201/129655)

Answer (score 3):

The first creates a block, which is not the same as a function. You can use anonymous self-executing functions to create local, private variables and return an interface from it. It's called the Module Pattern.

```
var Module = (function() {

    var method = function() { console.log("anonymous block"); },
        someOtherMethod = function() {};

    return { // return our interface as an object literal
        method: method,
        someOtherMethod: someOtherMethod
    };
})();

Module.method(); // "anonymous block"
```

We can call it, keeping the variables `method` and `someOtherMethod` isolated from the global scope. It's one of the most important, useful features of object-oriented programming in JS.

Comment: The cool thing is you can even refer to private variables. For example, in your `method`, you could increment a counter that's invisible to global scope and use it as a *reliable* way to track how many times the method has been called.

Answer (score 0):

`block 1` will have scope of the block it is inside, setting a var will overwrite it in the parent, you can use `let`.

```
var a = 2;
{
    var a = 4;
}
a; // === 4
```

`block 2` will have global scope but anything set by `var` will be forgotten after it is executed.

```
var a = 2;
(function(){
    var a = 4;
})();
a; // === 2
```

Comment: Javascript closures are on functions/scripts not blocks.

Comment: @jholloman - I think that's what shhac is saying -- that a block does not define an independent scope.

Comment: Yes, it only gives scope if you use the `let` from JavaScript 1.7 https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let