# Differences between self-invoking anonymous function formats

Tags: javascript, function

Self-invoking anonymous function should be like

```
(function() {

//....

})()
```

or

```
(function() {

//....

}())
```

But what is the difference between

```
(function() {

//....

})
```

What parameters will missing in the wrong one?

```
(function() {
    console.log('test');
    $(".dropdown-menu").dropdown();
})
```

Comment: That last example doesn't invoke dropdown.

Comment: A bit [similar question here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12325136/javascript-anonymous-function-syntax).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(function() {
    //...
})
```

is **NOT** a self-invoking anonymous function. Your `console.log` won't work but `$(".dropdown-menu").dropdown();` neither.

See my simplified **[example](http://jsfiddle.net/MutXF/)**.

Comment: I know it's not a self-invoking anonymous function, I've mention it in the question **the wrong one**

Comment: dropdown really works I've update a link.

Comment: @LiJung It works without any code there at all, too: http://jsfiddle.net/A8A2P/2/ I suspect the bootstrap.min.js file (added as an external resource) is adding that functionality for you; that anonymous function isn't being executed.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist oh... Thanks... I just realized...

Comment: Sorry... for a dumb question.

Comment: For completeness, what you have here is merely a _function expression_, but as it's not assigned to anything, and not invoked, it'll just get parsed and then ignored.

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference in first two examples you posted. They both are Self-invoking anonymous functions without any parameters. They are just using slightly different syntax.

It's also worth mentioning that these are not called `Self-invoking anonymous functions` anymore. They are known as `immediately-invoked function expression (IIFE)`

The last example is not self invoking functions because they haven't got parentheses which invokes/calls the function.

Comment: but the function will invoke `$(".dropdown-menu").dropdown()`, print nothing in console. Why?

Comment: It is not going to execute anything at all, that must be happening somewhere else.